# Cisco ASA 5520 is missing management interface

Tags: firewall, cisco, ios

The ASA 5520 `show version`  shows the following

```
Cisco Adaptive Security Appliance Software Version 8.4(2)

System image file is "Unknown, monitor mode tftp booted image"
Config file at boot was "startup-config"

ciscoasa up 1 hour 10 mins

Hardware:   ASA 5520, 1024 MB RAM, CPU Pentium II 1000 MHz
Internal ATA Compact Flash, 256MB
BIOS Flash unknown @ 0x0, 0KB


 0: Ext: GigabitEthernet0    : address is 0000.ab96.8d00, irq 0
 1: Ext: GigabitEthernet1    : address is 0000.ab44.cd01, irq 0
 2: Ext: GigabitEthernet2    : address is 0000.ab4e.3902, irq 0
 3: Ext: GigabitEthernet3    : address is 0000.abd9.ac03, irq 0
 4: Ext: GigabitEthernet4    : address is 0000.abb5.b804, irq 0
 5: Ext: GigabitEthernet5    : address is 0000.ab14.cf05, irq 0
```

I want to identify then configure the [management interface](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa84/configuration/guide/interface_start.html#wp1324550), however the output shows  there is no interface `Management`. How can the management interface be found? Is it missing from hardware or is it missing configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just your ASA doesn't have a dedicated management port.

Then you must setup one of your ASA interfaces to become management interface.

> The ASA 5510 and higher adaptive security appliance includes a dedicated management interface called Management 0/0, which is meant to support traffic to the security appliance. However, you can configure any interface to be a management-only interface using the management-only command.

The output you provided is from real device or from GNS3 simulator?

Comment: GNS3 / Qemu emulator. Management 0/0 doesn't show up anywhere in show-running-config.

Comment: Maybe GNS3 doesn't have any dedicated Management 0/0 port. My GNS3 provides the same output with you.

Do you try to config ethernet interface to become management interface?